# IE 6 / 7 / 8 Not loading all of the stylesheet

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

It's been an eventful day - I am recently just got rid of a malware add-on from my browsers that corrupted files in my localhost (I am using OSX), I have spent the day fixing it. it basically turned off my stylesheets and attempted to load in some advertising objects. Since then things havn't been 100% but I have removed it from my system and amended the files it attacked. Here is the URL I am having bother with

http://www.darcysbelfast.co.uk

On IE 6/7/8 It won't load in certain sections of the stylesheet, I have tried about everything to get this working but still haven't worked out the problem. I use Browserstack to test my sites in IE etc, it seems to load fine in every browser apart from the earlier versions of IE.
The last thing I want to do is write a conditional with all my styles in it, it'd obviously be nasty, are there any alternatives?

Comment: just run your css through a check for any errors.

Comment: This post doesn't make much sense to me... is that your site? Is it hosted on the OSX machine that got compromised? Why do you think the compromise has something to do with IE not seeing the CSS?

Comment: I can't click the url. This is the interwebs, right?

Comment: How many stylesheet files are there in the site -- IE8 and earlier has a limit of 31 stylesheet files. If you have more than that, the ones over the limit will be ignored.

Comment: Hey guys sorry my head is up my ass today, I built the site from my macbook that got compromised today, It only has one stylesheet - the mobile version is working absolutely fine with basically the same javascript/ html files which is at  [link](http://www.darcysbelfast.co.uk/mobile)

Comment: @webmaster777 - You ever heard of copy paste? :)

Answer (score 7):

The stylesheets load fine, the browser just doesn't have a clue how to apply them since you're using HTML5 elements like `section`, `footer` and `article`. You need to load a HTML5 DOM shim to patch support for these elements into IE8 and older. Add the following line of code at the end of your `<head>` and you should be fine:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Background info [can be found here](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Comment: Thank you so much, the section I read HTML5 elementsI slapped myself, you are a life-saver

Comment: Alternatively you can also include [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), it includes this patch for old IE versions as well.